# Android Studio 3.2 canary Exception in Studio core, StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start edit code in Android studio 3.2 canary for little time, the exception throw always.

[There is the bugs image crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmBO5.png)

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add a image crop, I had add it just now!